# Is there a playground / sandbox for Google Play Developer API?

Tags: android, google-play, sandbox, google-play-developer-api

is it possible to use a playground / sandbox for the Google Play Developer API? I am very much interested in:

- Retrieving a set of reviews
- Retrieving an individual review
- Replying to Reviews

... according to https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews

It would be nice to write a test review, because then I could test posting a reply via the API.

Comment: Did you find a playground/ sandbox? Maybe it took 6 years to find it? :)